# Defines a title using mouse cursor coordinates. Isometric social games

Tags: javascript, geometry, 2d-games, isometric

In the [Social Isometric Games](http://www.kings.k12.ca.us/tempdocs/making_isometric_social_real_time_games_with_html5_css3_and_javascript.pdf) book, page 53, there is a description of the method, that defines a title using mouse cursor coordinates. It works well, but it is not clear what principles are used to make it work. Can someone explain this algorithm in details? Maybe you have some links to the formula. Or maybe you can advise me on which field of science i should look at.

Here is an example of a code that I am interested in:

```
var col = (e.clientY - gridOffsetY) * 2;  //???
col = ((gridOffsetX + col) - e.clientX) / 2;  //???

var row = ((e.clientX + col) - tile.height) - gridOffsetX; //???
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to attach a link. corrected

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, height of the rhombus cell is 2*p, width is 4*p, where p is characteristic size value.

Let's coordinates of base point - top vertice of top cell is (0, 0).

So top-right edge vector is `tr=(2p, p)`, top-left vector is `tl=(-2p, p)`.

Let's mouse point is `(mx, my)` relative to base point. To find what cell it belongs to, one could decompose vector `(mx, my)` by basis vectors `tl, tr`

```
 mx = R * tl.x + C * tr.x
 my = R * tl.y + C * tr.y
 or
 mx = R * 2 * p + C * p
 my = R * (- 2 * p) + C * p
```

to find C , we can add both equations

```
mx + my = 2 * C * p
C = (mx + my) / (2 * p)
column = Floor(C)  //integer part of C
```

to find R, subtract equations

```
R = (mx - my) / (4 * p)
row = Floor(R)
```

other calculations take into account shift of the grid on the screen